# Копировать в буфер обмена содержимое тега по клику

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const inp = document.querySelector('#input');
const out = document.querySelector('#output');
const btn = document.querySelector('#fix');
const writeBtn = document.querySelector('#copy');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const text = inp.value;
  output.innerText = text.replace(/<\s*(\/)?\s*([^>\s]+)\s*(\s[^>]*)?>/g, '<$1$2$3>');  
});
writeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(output)
});
```

```html
<button id="copy">Copy</button>
<hr/>
<textarea id="input">
< p>12334</p>
<p >fjfg< / p>
<p attr="a b c">fjfg< / p>
<p attr="a b c" >fjfg< / p>
</textarea>

<pre id=output></pre>
<hr/>
<button id="fix">Fix</button>
```

Cначала кликаю на `fix`, разорванные угловые скобки заменяются на правильные, потом после клика на copy нужно, чтобы получившееся содержимое тега `<pre>` скопировалось в буфер обмена. Как реализовать? Кое-что пытался сделать, но не выходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Строкой: `output.innerText =
  text.replace(/<\s*(\/)?\s*([^>\s]+)\s*(\s[^>]*)?>/g, '<$1$2$3>');` —
  поместили данные тег `<pre>`;
- далее необходимо сохранить данные (наверно, вы забыли) из тега
  `<pre>`;

```js
const inp = document.querySelector('#input');
const out = document.querySelector('#output');
const btn = document.querySelector('#fix');
const writeBtn = document.querySelector('#copy');
let pre_content = '';

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const text = inp.value;
  output.innerText = text.replace(/<\s*(\/)?\s*([^>\s]+)\s*(\s[^>]*)?>/g, '<$1$2$3>');
  pre_content = output.textContent;
});
writeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(pre_content)
});
```

```html
<button id="copy">Copy</button>
<hr/>
<textarea id="input">
< p>12334</p>
<p >fjfg< / p>
<p attr="a b c">fjfg< / p>
<p attr="a b c" >fjfg< / p>
</textarea>

<pre id=output></pre>
<hr/>
<button id="fix">Fix</button>
```

Comment: гм, да уж) спс.